# Can create Elastic Beanstalk application through web interface , but not through awscli/ebcli with same account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

Trying to learn AWS. Went to EB on the web interface, created an application and an environment, uploaded code, no problem.

Trying to do the same through the CLI - created an access key for my account, used `aws configure set` to set access key and secret. However, when I type `eb init` and choose the same region I used in the web app, the first fishy thing is that it doesn't let me choose the existing app like the `eb init` documentation said it would, it just asks me for a name to create a new app.

And when I do try to create a new one, I get this:

```
ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. User: arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/[my account] is not authorized to perform: elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplication on resource: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-central-1:xxx:application/test
```

What am I doing wrong? This is definitely the same account I used to create through the web app, and I have checked if someone removed my privileges or something - my account still has AdministratorAccess and I can keep creating apps through the web interface to my heart's content.

Comment: I guess something must be wrong with your credentials. Does `aws sts get-caller-identity` work? Does it return the expected user/role ARN?

Comment: It works and it does.

Comment: Then I guess you should work through some aws cli commands until you find one which fails: `aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments`, `aws elasticbeanstalk create-application`, etc

Comment: aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments wants me to provide a region. If I pass it --region eu-central-1 (the one I used in the web interface), it returns a blank array.

Comment: If you have already deployed some environments, try `eb list` to list your current environments. In case you have multiple aws profiles for aws cli, try passing the profile name explicitly to eb command (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html). This helps to make sure, eb is correctly configured.

Comment: Can you try providing eb specific policy `AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk` to your user. If that doesn't work you can try creating a new IAM user with administrator/powerUser access and see if it works. Also, do provide region in your config file `~/.aws/config`

Comment: `AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk` worked for me. Also you can clone this policy and make it more granular